# What do we do with questions that are actually answers?

Tags: discussion, triage

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750909/unable-switch-to-webview-several-times-on-ios) post while reviewing Triage.

Here, the person appears to post an answer to a problem they faced, but as a question.

I do not have knowledge of the specific topic at hand, and so could not gauge it's usefulness. The first thing I thought of was flagging it, but I am not sure what reason would be applicable.

- Spam? It is not promoting anything.
- Rude or abusive? Nope.
- Duplicate? I did have a look around, and it does not appear to be a duplicate.
- Should be closed? Does not appear to be off-topic or opinionated.

I want to ask:

- Should this person have asked the question and answered it separately?
- Should these "questions" be flagged? If so, under what?
- Should we close them? Or can they be useful?
- Should we take into consideration any factors (helpfulness etc)?
- Any further tips?

Update: The question has now been [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closed) as ["Needs details or clarity
"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: _"Should this person have asked the question and answered it separately"_ There is an option to answer your question at the same time as posting it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can the question be answered?

Is it clear what are they asking?

Can a third party edit salvage the question?

I say **no** to all of the above. The question should be closed as *unclear*, so flagging/voting for closure would be the right approach.

Comment: Okay... Will still wait for some time before accepting an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: for general case it may be possible to edit a question of this kind into Q&A pair, but for this particular case it's hard to know what OP was trying to solve (also someone who had such error may actually be able to convert it).